# Getting object instead of array in Tabulator

Tags: json, tabulator

It seems that Tabulator is expecting an array from the JSON feed (accessed via the `ajax URL` method) starting and ending with `[]`, but sometimes, there is only one result - so that  it just starts and ends with `{}`

This is evident in the error thrown:

```
Data Loading Error - Unable to process data due to invalid data type 
Expecting: array 
Received:  object
```

Is there any way around this?

My Data looks like this, for a *single* result:

```
{"empId":"123456","firstName":"bini the third","lastName":"rouge","birthDate":"1986-05-04T00:00:00.000+0000","gender":"M","mother":false}
```

and like this for a multiple row result:

```
[
 {"empId":"123456","firstName":"bini the third","lastName":"rouge","birthDate":"1986-05-04T00:00:00.000+0000","gender":"M","mother":false},
 {"empId":"1111","firstName":"bini the third","lastName":"rouge","birthDate":"1976-05-04T00:00:00.000+0000","gender":"M","mother":false}
]
```

As you can see, the `[]` are added in for when multiple rows are returned, but not present for a single result

Comment: Are you the developer of API sending the JSON? If so, just program it so the API will always return an array. Ambiguous return-types on one endpoint usually suck.

Comment: Will try that thanks. But still wondering if Tabulator can consume this format without the `[]`.

Answer (score 0):

To alter the response see here:

http://tabulator.info/docs/4.7/data#ajax

Ajax Response Format

```
Altering The Response

Tabulator expects the response to an ajax request to be a JSON encoded string representing an array of data objects. If you need to pass other data back in your request as well, you can use the ajaxResponse callback to process the returned data before it is passed to the table. The return value of this callback should be an array of row data objects.

var table = new Tabulator("#example-table", {
    ajaxResponse:function(url, params, response){
        //url - the URL of the request
        //params - the parameters passed with the request
        //response - the JSON object returned in the body of the response.

        return response.tableData; //return the tableData property of a response json object
    },
});
```

There you could enclose your single object in an array to return to Tabulator.

A simple example:

```
ajaxResponse: function(url, params, response){
        if( Object.prototype.toString.call(response) === '[object Array]' ) {
            return response;
            
       }else{if( Object.prototype.toString.call(response) === '[object Object]' ) {
           var rsArray = [];
           rsArray.push(response)
           return rsArray;
    }


       }
    }
```

Comment: Thank you. Would you be able to setup a VERY quick demo for this? TY!

Comment: I added an example. Unfortunately I have not figured out how to get jsFiddle to work with AJAX request/response, so I don't have a live example.

Comment: that is an easy one Adrian, if you add another file to the fiddle like `test.json` that contains JSON formatted data then use `./test.json` as the ajaxUrl value

Comment: Hmm. I can't seem to figure out how to add a file to a jsFiddle. Any examples you can point me at?